# How to find synchronous IDs based on timestamp and value

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to find synchronous data entries, which share a certain value ("ref") over a certain amount of timestamps.

**Dummy Data:**

```
library(data.table)

dft <- data.table(
  id = rep(1:5, each=5),
  time = rep(1:5, 5),
  ref = c(10,11,11,11,11,
          10,11,11,11,21,
          20,31,31,31,31,
          20,41,41,41,41,
          20,51,51,51,51)
)

setorder(dft, time)
dft[, time := as.POSIXct(time, origin = "2018-10-14")]
dft
```

---

In that example the ID's 1 and 2 would be synchronous over 4 timestamps in line 1,2,6,7,11,12,16,17, as they share the same `ref` value (rows are marked with **!**). NOTE: They share the same ref value within one timestamp and might share another ref value in the next timestamp.

How could I approach that problem? I would also like to define the amount of timestamps where the values have to be identical. If I define that at least 5 timestamps have to be synchronous, no ID's should result in that example. With 4 or lower, the ID's 1&2 should be shown as synchronous data-entries.

I have to do that calculation over several millions of rows, so I would prefer a `data.table` or `dplyr` solution or any other performant solution (SQL would also be fine).

```
    id                time ref
 1:  1 2018-10-14 02:00:01  10    !
 2:  2 2018-10-14 02:00:01  10    !
 3:  3 2018-10-14 02:00:01  20
 4:  4 2018-10-14 02:00:01  20
 5:  5 2018-10-14 02:00:01  20
 6:  1 2018-10-14 02:00:02  11    !
 7:  2 2018-10-14 02:00:02  11    !
 8:  3 2018-10-14 02:00:02  31
 9:  4 2018-10-14 02:00:02  41
10:  5 2018-10-14 02:00:02  51
11:  1 2018-10-14 02:00:03  11    !
12:  2 2018-10-14 02:00:03  11    !
13:  3 2018-10-14 02:00:03  31
14:  4 2018-10-14 02:00:03  41
15:  5 2018-10-14 02:00:03  51
16:  1 2018-10-14 02:00:04  11    !
17:  2 2018-10-14 02:00:04  11    !
18:  3 2018-10-14 02:00:04  31
19:  4 2018-10-14 02:00:04  41
20:  5 2018-10-14 02:00:04  51
21:  1 2018-10-14 02:00:05  11
22:  2 2018-10-14 02:00:05  21
23:  3 2018-10-14 02:00:05  31
24:  4 2018-10-14 02:00:05  41
25:  5 2018-10-14 02:00:05  51
```

---

Benchmarking both examples from @DavidArenburg:

```
library(microbenchmark)

mc = microbenchmark(times = 100,
  res1 = dft[dft, .(id, id2 = x.id), on = .(id > id, time, ref), nomatch = 0L, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, .N, by = .(id, id2)],
  res2= dft[dft, .(pmin(id, i.id), pmax(id, i.id)), on = .(time, ref), allow.cartesian=TRUE][V1 != V2, .(synced = .N / 2L), by = .(id1 = V1, id2 = V2)]
)

mc
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
>  res1 156.8389 158.8122 165.1828 159.6931 165.9156 292.7987   100  a 
>  res2 311.1658 324.5684 350.3006 331.4310 343.6755 815.8397   100   b
> ```

Comment: Please, clarify _they share the same `ref` value_. Do they share the same `ref` values across all 4 timestamps, or do they share the same `ref` value within one timestamp and share another `ref` value in the next timestamp?

Comment: Also, please, clarify _amount of timestamps_. Do you mean consecutive timestamps?

Comment: Would that work? `dft[dft, .(pmin(id, i.id), pmax(id, i.id)), on = .(time, ref)][V1 != V2, .(synced = .N / 2L), by = .(id1 = V1, id2 = V2)]`?

Comment: The `ref` value has to be identical for 1 timestamp and can be different at the next timestamp. And the "synchronicity" doesnt have to be over consecutive timestamps. In the example: If rows 6&7 wouldnt be identical, the ID pair 1&2 would still have 3 synchronous entries.

Comment: @David Thank you, this looks quite interesting and correct for that example. And Thank you for correcting the bad syntax ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think your code works great. If you could explain the code a bit and post it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: But that only does counts, you wanted to add an `"!"` to each row, no?

Comment: No, the counts are fine. The `"!"` where just for illustration in the example.

Comment: Ok, I've posted a much simpler solution, it should perform better, but it assumes that `id` is a numeric/integer column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible data.table solution

```
dft[dft, .(id, id2 = x.id), # get the desired columns
         on = .(id > id, time, ref), # the join condition
         nomatch = 0L, # remove unmatched records (NAs)
         allow.cartesian = TRUE # In case of a big join, allow Cartesian join 
     ][, .N, by = .(id, id2)] # Count obs. per ids combinations

#    id id2 N
# 1:  1   2 4
# 2:  3   4 1
# 3:  3   5 1
# 4:  4   5 1
```

---

**Explanation**

We do a self join on `time` and `ref`, while specifying `id > id` so we won't join to the same `id` and extracting the joined ids (`id` and `x.id` which are the joined ids from *both* data sets) while removing all the unmatched rows ( `nomatch = 0L`) . Finally, we count the matched combinations (`.N` is a special symbol in data.table that stores the number of obs. per combination).

---

Old (and a bit more involved solution)

```
dft[dft, .(pmin(id, i.id), pmax(id, i.id)), on = .(time, ref)
    ][V1 != V2, .(synced = .N / 2L), by = .(id1 = V1, id2 = V2)]
```

Comment: Applied on the real dataset, I am getting this error: `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 94860097 rows; more than 320000 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.`

Comment: Including `allow.cartesian=TRUE` will work for the big dataset. `dft[dft, .(id, id2 = x.id), on = .(id > id, time, ref), nomatch = 0L, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, .N, by = .(id, id2)]`

Comment: Yeah, that happens if the resulting join is bigger than the original data set. That means that you have many overlapping ids. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Btw, did you compare the performance of the two solutions? I'm interested to know if there is a big difference on a big data set.

Comment: I will include a benchmark for both, but with the "old" code (including `allow.cartesian=TRUE`) on the real dataset I got that error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.4 Gb`

Comment: Yeah, that's because it does a full self join, while the second one does only a partial join, this is the main reason I wrote a new version. Though both should work with enough memory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I included a benchmark for both examples and indeed the partial join is about twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Translating @David Arenburgs code to **SQL** gives me:

```
SELECT a.id as id, b.id as id2, count(*) FROM testdata a
INNER JOIN testdata b ON a.ref = b.ref AND a.timest = b.timest
WHERE a.id > b.id 
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

And selecting only those *with count > 1*:

```
SELECT a.id as id, b.id as id2, count(*) FROM testdata a
INNER JOIN testdata b ON a.ref = b.ref AND a.timest = b.timest
WHERE a.id > b.id 
GROUP BY a.id, b.id HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

---

Code to produce the SQL-table with the resulting dataframe (`dft`) from the question:

**R:**

```
fwrite(x = dft, file = "C:/testdata.csv", row.names = F)
```

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE testdata (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  timest timestamp,
  ref integer
  );

COPY testdata(id, timest, ref) 
FROM 'C:/testdata.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```